# How can I keep my header fixed and still scroll?

Tags: html, css, header, sidebar

I need my header and side bar to stay in place, but I also need to scroll down on the page. 
I'm using fixed positioning, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Show your code , Please :)

Comment: It wont left me, this is my first time on this website:| Sorry I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

Add this `position:fixed;` to your style of parts which you want to stay in fix !

Or

Reference [this](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header-and-left-sidebar) link !

Comment: I did that but it won't let me scroll down on my page.
p{
font-family:century gothic;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 14%;
}

div {
 border-radius: 5px;
}
#dw {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -40%;
}
#header {
 float: top;
 z-index: 1;
 position:fixed ;
 width: 98.8%;
 margin-top: -20px;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #f93986;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

Answer (score 0):

You can put your content in an iframe and the header and sidebar can be in the top. In this way. You can set the overflow for the iframe element. Probably this could help you out with your requirement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem was in your HTML, not your CSS.  The `<body>` tag should encompass all of your content. and don't forget to close your `<div></div>`. I also moved your body background into the css, try to avoid using inline styles unless you **really** have to.

```
<head>
    <Title>About Me!</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="aboutme.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Updated Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/C4mNR/6/)

Comment: #header {
 float: top;
 z-index: 1;
 position: fixed;
 width: 98.8%;
 margin-top: -20px;
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #f93986;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

} If I take the fixed positioning off of this, I can scroll and my sidebar is fixed, but when I put it back on I'm not able to scroll.

Comment: @JasmineLawson can you put the related code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) It will be easier for everyone to help, if we can see what we're dealing with.

Comment: @JasmineLawson you can also edit your question and include code there. Hit the button with brackets on it -> "{ }" and it will give you a highlighted box to paste code into.

Comment: @JasmineLawson If you're new to Stack Overflow check out the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) pages.